# Why does python library "python-pptx" doesn't get all selection data?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am writing a python script using the `pptx` library, where I try to get the text at `Title 4` box. Unfortunately python is not able to identify all the shape in the some slides, thus missing some of the shapes.

Here is my code

```
from pptx import Presentation
import glob

prs = Presentation('abc.pptx')
slides = prs.slides
for slide in prs.slides:
    print('\nslide number ', slides.index(slide)+1)
    for shape in slide.placeholders:
        print(shape.name)

#prs.save()
```

I am getting this output for slide 6

```
slide number  6
Chart Placeholder 8
Content Placeholder 10
Chart Placeholder 16
Chart Placeholder 12
Chart Placeholder 19
```

But as I can clearly see in the pptx file I have a few more elements/shapes than what the python script detects.

[image]

Any idea why the shapes/selection like `Title 4`,`Textbox 6` etc is missed?

Comment: I don't know the library, but are all shapes considered to be "placeholders"? Looking at the documentation for the VBA powerpoint object model (which this python library seems to be a wrapper over) there is a `Shapes` collection which seems to be not the same thing as the `Placeholders` collection.

Comment: I'm not sure, I assumed textbox,title box and all other shapes comes under placeholders

Comment: There is some distinction, I'm not sure what it is. Perhaps it has to do with *how* the shape was inserted and not what it is? In any event, the Python library also has a shapes collection for any slide object, so it couldn't hurt to iterate over that as an experiment.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your suggestion @JohnColeman I will have a look at it. There is a very high chance I might have missed it from the documentation since I'm a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders are a subset of the shapes on a slide and are contributed by the slide layout. Other shapes can be added after slide creation and placeholder shapes can be removed.

To get *all* shapes on a slide, use the `slide.shapes` property. `slide.placeholders` restricts that list to the placeholder shapes.

Comment: Using `slide.shapes` instead of `slide.placeholders` works. Thanks @scanny

Comment: Hi @scanny, 
slide.shapes and slide.placeholders both are not work for me!
Do you have any other way to get all selection pane list from python pptx library?